# взаимодействие с пользователем в файле php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Начал изучать php, решил написать сайт куда пользователь может добавлять продукт и его параметры (калорийность, бжу и так далее).

```html
<form method="POST" action="product_handler.php" id="newProduct" onsubmit="validate_productInfo(this);return false;">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Новый продукт</legend>
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Название продукта" class="validate" id="productName">
        <button type="submit" id="sendProductInfo">Добавить</button>
 </fieldset>
</form>
```

При добавлении нового продукта решил проверять есть ли такой продукт УЖЕ в бд и в этом случае предлагать пользователю переписать для него параметры. Тут возникло непонимание. При submit'e нового продукта передаю данные обработчику (файлик php), где провожу проверку по БД и выясняю что строка с таким продуктом уже есть.

```
$userProduct_rqst = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT COUNT(`product_name`) FROM `product_value` WHERE `user_name` = '".$_COOKIE['userName'].
  "' AND `product_name` = '*название продукта*'");

if(mysqli_fetch_assoc($userProduct_rqst)['product_name']>0){}
```

Как организовать в этот момент взаимодействие с пользователем, чтобы предложить переписать значения?

1. Выводить confirm в обработчике? Мне кажется дефолтный он выглядит не очень, а для его кастомизации в файлике, который подразумевался как чистый php-обработчик, придется городить js код с html разметкой и стилями.
2. Перебрасывать пользователя из обработчика обратно на страницу и спрашивать "хотите ли вы переписать значения для продукта?", чтобы после этого снова переключаться на обработчик и уже в нем перезаписывать значения? В $_SESSION придется хранить во время перебрасываний все значения для запроса, да и сами перебрасывания постоянные туда-сюда будут мозолить глаза мне кажется.
3. Думал в функции validate_productInfo перед submit'ом проверять встроенным в js php запросом есть ли продукт в БД, но оказывается я не могу просто передать в php переменную из js кода, в которой содержится название этого продукта.

```js
function validate_productInfo(info){
            let product=document.getElementById('productName').value
            var test = "";
            test=<?php  
                $_SESSION['product'] = "'" . ?>; product; <?php . "'";
                $userProduct_rqst = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT COUNT(`product_name`) FROM `product_value` WHERE `user_name` = '" . $_COOKIE['userName'] . "' AND `product_name` = '" . <?php product ?>; .  "'");
                print_r(json_encode(mysqli_fetch_assoc($userProduct_rqst)));
            ?>;
            console.log(test);
```

Хотел название продукта и в суперглобальную переменную положить и в сам mysql запрос встроить, но потом понял, что, кажется, так не работает.

Подскажите как вы видите выход из этой ситуации? Или все же придется заморачиваться с пунктом 2, который хотя бы выглядит как рабочий вариант.

Answer (score 0):

все дело в том что PHP и JS с HTML
немного разные вещи
например PHP выполняется у вас 1 раз на СЕРВЕРЕ в момент вызова программы
JS работает с БРАУЗЕРОМ
то что вы нагородили в JS может и выполнится но в момент вызова js скрипта, но никак не с пользовательских действий в БРАУЗЕРЕ

Для того чтобы вы могли проверить результат работы БРАУЗЕРА на СЕРВЕРЕ
вам необходимо послать на СЕРВЕР данные
в вашем случае POST запрос
на этот запрос СЕРВЕР должен сгенерировать ответ который отобразится в БРАУЗЕРЕ
если вы хотите отправить запрос без перезагрузки страницы и получить так-же ответ, воспользуйтесь ajax запросом например...
обработайте запрос на СЕРВЕРЕ и верните ответ БРАУЗЕРУ
потом при помощи JS вы сможете отобразить ответ в БРАУЗЕРЕ